# Git successfully stages file but fails to commit the file

Tags: linux, git, git-commit, git-diff

Git successfully stages the files via `git add` (they show up under "Changes to be committed"), but when I run `git commit -m "commit message"` and friends, the command silently fails (`echo $?` displays `1`) and my files are still sitting there listed as "Changes to be committed"...

Other similar questions suggested things such as:

- The `.git` file potentially being corrupted, with the solution being to re-clone into a separate directory, copy changed files there, and re-attempt the add/commit cycle. This did not help.
- There being some sort of permissions issue with the files, and to `chmod 755` before retrying. This was not relevant for me as the files were already `0755`.
- Restarting the computer. I actually did try this (cuz who knows) but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While debugging my problem, I did eventually find someone who pointed out the `GIT_TRACE` environment variable. I ran:

```
export GIT_TRACE=1
```

and after doing this, I re-ran my failing commit command. Now I saw that before just dying, it was actually trying to run `git diff` under the hood as part of its commit process. I had seen during my extensive searching through SO that sometimes `git diff` can fail on large files due to running out of memory but this had not seemed relevant to me since I was trying to `git commit`. The files in question were in fact large text files though (several MB).

The solution ultimately was to create a `.gitattributes` file, with entries like the following (sort of like `.gitignore` but with the binary keyword at the end):

```
problem/file/path/or/pattern binary
```

This way git would treat the file as a binary file and not run diff (and thus not run out of memory, and not fail to commit). This was an acceptable solution for me since I don't really need change tracking or anything on this particular file.

Comment: Thank you, especially for `export GIT_TRACE=1` which also helped my find my problem, which was in a pre-commit hook (a silently failing command).